# HttpClient GET transform response array of Objects

Tags: angular6, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

Following is my model.

```
export interface AuditTrail {
    logAction:string,
    targetEmpId:string,
    createdDate:Date
}
```

Code below retrieves data from a GET call and transforms it.

```
  public getAuditTrails() {
   return this.http.get<AuditTrail[]>(this.auditTrailUrl)
    .pipe(
      map((data :Object[]) =>  {
        return data.map(value => {
          const auditTrail:AuditTrail = {
            logAction:value["logAction"],
            targetEmpId:value["targetEmpId"]["empCode"],
            createdDate:value["loggedDateTime"]
          }
          return auditTrail;
        });
    })
    )
  }
```

This code works alright. However my question is how can I avoid the array
iteration `data.map(value => {`and use `rxjs` operators for the same.

The question is intended to improve my understanding of `rxjs` operators hence the solution should use rxjs operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to final return value to be, i.e., a stream of `AuditTrail` objects or a single `AuditTrail[]` array.

Stream:

```
public getAuditTrails(): Observable<AuditTrail> {
 return this.http.get<SomeObject[]>(this.auditTrailUrl).pipe(
   flatMap(data => data),
   map<SomeObject, AuditTrail>(value => ({
     logAction:value["logAction"],
     targetEmpId:value["targetEmpId"]["empCode"],
     createdDate:value["loggedDateTime"]
   })
 );
}
```

Above, `flatMap` is taking the source array and emitting each value as an item in a new observable stream allowing each individual item to be passed to a subsequent `map`.

Array:

If you want this to be reduced to an array, you can pipe `toArray`:

```
public getAuditTrails(): Observable<AuditTrail> {
 return this.http.get<AuditTrail[]>(this.auditTrailUrl).pipe(
   flatMap(data => data),
   map<SomeObject, AuditTrail>(value => ({
     logAction:value["logAction"],
     targetEmpId:value["targetEmpId"]["empCode"],
     createdDate:value["loggedDateTime"]
   }),
   toArray()
 );
}
```

Personally, I don't think there's any advantage to flat mapping and using `map(data = data.map(...))` is fine.